# Sql server use variable in selection top row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that select top X from Table,

```
declare @i int ;
set @i = 10 ;
select top @i from tableNam
```

> Incorrect syntax near '@i'.

What should i do ?

suppose that the @i comes from parameters in my storedProcedure

Comment: `SELECT TOP(@i)...` will work, while `SELECT TOP @i...` will not. Why? I don't know.

Comment: You did not include any column selection within your select clause.

Comment: Thank you, this is the point that i lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the variable in parenthesis to make it work.

```
declare @i int ;
set @i = 10 ;
select top (@i) * from tableNam
```

If you take the cursor to the error line you will find the reason as to why you need the parenthesis like this:

[image]

So the value should be a integer. Also if you see the [TOP keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) from MSDN then it says to use the parenthesis. The syntax said by MSDN is:

```
[ 
    TOP (expression) [PERCENT]
    [ WITH TIES ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Following syntax will work

```
declare @i int ;
set @i = 10 ;
select top (@i) * from sys.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic query to get the result:

```
declare @i int ;
set @i = 10;

DECLARE @SqlQury VARCHAR(500) = '';
SET @SqlQury = 'SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR) + ' * FROM tablename';
-- PRINT @SqlQury
EXEC (@SqlQury)
```

Comment: Forgetting that this is overkill and a lot more complicated than it needs to be, it will also run into errors for higher numbers. You should cast to `VARCHAR(10)`. If you cast `10000000` to `VARCHAR(5)` the result is `*`, meaning the query you end up with is `SELECT * * FROM tablename`, which won't work.